# How to encode password while mapping from DTO to entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, orika

In Spring Boot App I want to map a simple (login,pass) `UserDTO` to a User Entity using Orika Mapper. I have no idea how to encode password calling `PasswordEncoder.encode` method while mapping.
Should I use a different mapper?

Comment: Can't you map the DTO to entity explicitly and set the encoded password while setting the password field of the entity? This way you can encode the plain password from the DTO using BCryptPasswordEncoder.

Comment: @AdilKhalil Can you supply an example? Wtorix, do you understand Adil's suggestion?

Comment: I have added an example in the answer. Please note that this is pretty basics, I would recommend you to read more about Spring boot.

Comment: @Adil Khalil I've just build a service that converts/encodes passwords, a very similiar one to your example. 
The essence of my question is, how to do it using Orika mapper. From what i have found on web it is common to just map it on my own building a custom service. 
Anyway thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 1):

Before Mapping to Entity, you can use default encoder of Spring5 which works as below

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
      throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user")
          .password("password")
          .roles("USER");
    }
```

For more detail you can check here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-default-password-encoder

Comment: I know how the default encoder works. I wanted to know how to call: encode method while mapping from UserDto to User entity using Orika (UserDto password mapped to User encoded password). 
I've decided to build a Converter instead of using Orika.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For example, if your entity is something like

```
@Entity
public class User{
 private long id;
 private String username;
 private String encodedPassword;

 //getters and setters
}
```

and your UserDTO is

```
public class UserDTO{
 private String username;
 private String plainPassword;
 //getters and setters
}
```

In your controller class or service, you can do something like

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
...
@Controller
public class UserController{
...
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@PostMapping ...
public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody UserDTO dto){
User user = new User();
user.setUsername(dto.getUsername());
//Following line encodes password and set it for Entity
user.setEncodedPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(dto.getPlainPassword()));

...

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to find something like this:

```java
@Component
public class MyOwnMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public MyOwnMapper(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {

        addAdvancedMappers(factory);
    }

    private void addAdvancedMappers(MapperFactory factory) {

        factory.classMap(SourceDTO.class, DestinationEntity.class)
                .byDefault()
                .customize(new CustomMapper<>() {
                        public void mapAtoB(SourceDTO a, DestinationEntity b, MappingContext context) {
                            String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(a.getPassword());
                            b.setPassword(encodedPassword);
                        }
                    }
                ).register();
    }
}
```

within this configuration, you will just autowire MapperFacade wherever you want and use map methods.